# How to append a value to a not yet existing key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, append

I have a dictionary like this:

```
dct = {'one': 'value', 
       'two': ['value1','value2','value1'], 
       'three':['otherValue1','otherValue2','otherValue1'],
       'dontCareAboutThisKey':'debug'}
```

I need to remove duplicate values from the lists. I wrote a function to do this:

```
no_dups = {}
    for keys in dct:
        if isinstance(dct[keys], list) and keys != 'dontCareAboutThisKey':
            for value in dct[keys]:
                if value not in no_dups.values():
                    no_dups[keys].append(value)
        else:
            no_dups[keys] = dct[keys]
```

I'm checking if value of the current key is a list. If no, it just 'copy' key to `no_dups` dictionary. If it is a list and not a key that I don't care about (there are no duplicates for sure) - it should check if current value already exists in `no_dups.values()` and append it to current key. Problem is that I'm getting an error:

`KeyError: 'two:'`

I know it's because I'm trying to add a value to non existing key but I have no idea how to deal with this and make it work.

Comment: On which line throws error?

Comment: `no_dups[keys].append(value)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to deal with adding the key and appending at the same time is with dicts' [`setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method:

```
no_dups.setdefault(keys,[]).append(value)
```

But rather than that, you can do this in a more neat way like this:

```
#remove duplicates
no_dups = {k:list(set(v)) if isinstance(v, list) and k != 'dontCareAboutThisKey' else v 
           for k,v in dct.items()}  # or dct.iteritems() if using python2.x
```

That hack will, for key value combinations that pass the `if` test, convert the list into a set (removing duplicates) and then in a list again. For other key value combinations it will leave it intact.

Comment: It's quite hard to understand this, but I'll try. Thank you :)

Comment: Great, no magic there, Python is really powerful with comprehensions and is good to practice them.

Comment: I know, I know.. but `Learning Python` has 1500 pages and I can't read so fast. Thanks for answer again :)

Answer (score 2):

```
dct = {'one': 'value', 
       'two': ['value1','value2','value1'], 
       'three':['otherValue1','otherValue2','otherValue1'],
       'dontCareAboutThisKey':'debug'}
```

`set(dct)` returns a `set`, which is a list without duplicates:

```
for key, value in dct.items():
    if not isinstance(value, basestring):
        dct[key] = set(value)
```

If you need a new dictionary you could do:

```
new_dct = {}
for key, value in dct.items():
    if not isinstance(value, basestring):
        new_dct[key] = set(value)
    else:
        new_dct[key] = value
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP really wants to create a copy, as this will edit inplace... but... seems a fine approach to me

Comment: I didn't know about `set()`. Now it's much easier. Thank you. I would like to accept two answers but it is impossible. Paulo Bu was firs with `set()` function so I'll accept his answer but I'll use your because it's not complicated for begginer user :)

Answer (score 1):

If You want to remove duplicates, just change You list to set, with set() function:

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

It automatically gives You unique set, then You can always change it back to list.

Comment: Thank you for information about sets. I'll remember this :)